# jQuery get currect active slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get current active slide, and when change slide I get the new one?
I've try with:

```
    $('#carouselExampleIndicators').bind('slid', function() {
    let currentIndex = $('button.active').index() + 1;
   alert(currentIndex)
});
```

but not working
This is JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moku23/65p0r9f1/6/

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve by binding an event handler for `slid` to the indicators ... The proper way to handle events with the Bootsrap v5 carousel, is explained here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#events

Comment: `slid` -> `$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slid.bs.carousel'...`

Answer (score 1):

Use [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```js
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
   currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
   console.log(currentIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--- s__carousel -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <span id="num"></span>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
                    aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">1
            </button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">
                2
            </button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">
                3
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner" style="he">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Bootstrap Carousel documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#events), you can see that the correct event is `slid.bs.carousel`, and also that it provides 4 additional properties to the event that's passed to the handler. One of which, `from`, is the index of the current slide.

In addition, `bind()` is deprecated and should not be used. Change your code to use `on()` instead. I'd also check to make sure you're using an up to date version of jQuery. The latest version is 3.6.0.

```js
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slid.bs.carousel', e => {
  let currentIndex = e.from;
  // your logic here...
});
```

Here's a full working version of your fiddle:

```js
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slid.bs.carousel', e => {
  let currentIndex = e.from;
  let newIndex = e.to;
  
  console.log(currentIndex, newIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span id="num"></span>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">1</button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">2</button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner" style="he">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```